# Tank track rotation around itself without array modifier

Tags: animation, modifiers, rigging, objects, curve-modifier

[image]

Tank track rotation around itself without array modifier,I want this object to rotate around itself without using array?

Comment: What about a curve modifier?  Is that okay?

Comment: I tried it and it made the whole shape follow the curve

Comment: https://www.loom.com/share/af2b49cb383843708cdcfd79a472f7f9